# Why is supabase update not working for me?

Tags: sveltekit, supabase, row-level-security, supabase-database

[image]

I am trying to update a user's name in the profiles table. This command works when i disable rls on the table but not when it is on. When the function is called the error is null, data is just an empty array.
The user is authenticated by the way.

I tried multiple variations of RLS policy for updating but nothing seemed to have worked. I tried enabling update with auth.uid() = id, setting role to authenticated and a couple of other combinations but nothing works. I am sure it is something with RLS because updating works when I disable RLS. I am using sveltekit by the way and i think the problem might be in the user authentication not being passed to supabase update or something like that

Comment: The usual cause of this is that your user isn't authenticated on the SSR side of things. When using SSR frameworks like SvelteKit it's best to use the Supabase Auth Helpers and not use the Supabase JS library directly.

Comment: Found a solution?